# Baking large heightmap not creating correctly colored image

Tags: texture-baking, height-map

If i create a small mesh and bake it out i get the a correctly baked heightmap image.
However if i have a large mesh the baked the heightmap the resulting image is almost completely white.

How can i accurately correct the output to account for the scale of the larger mesh ?

Attached is two images of the same mesh with one scaled up, where you can clearly see the issue.

[image: Small mesh With correct colors]
[image: The same mesh just scaled up, the resulting image is almost completely white]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the *Position* output works but you could use the *Generated* output of the *Texture Coordinate*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, its much appreciated. The problem i have with using the texture coordinate is mapping it to the correct 0 - 1 range. So it goes from 0 "solid black" at the lowest point of the mesh to just under 1 "fully white" at the highest.

Comment: @SarahLee What exactly is your problem there? The _Generated_ output of the _Texture Coordinate_ node does exactly this, mapping 0 to 1 from the lowest to the highest point, no matter how large the object is. Or is it not giving you real black and white when you are viewing it? That's maybe because you have set the _Color Management_ to _Filmic_? If you change it to _View Transform_ > _Standard_ and _Look_ > _None_, the colors should be correct.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann ah yes that was the issue when baking. my Colour Management settings were set to filmic. Is there a way to know how much to displace the mesh so the height is correct? Currently im adjusting it manually, the reason I ask is because when I import it into a game engine for example it asks for a height scale?